# one to many mapping using Lists and join table

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I m using one-to-many mapping for List using join table.
There are lot of examples available on net of this mapping using Sets but not with Lists.

Consider tables:

```
Table Ticket
{
ticketid int PK;
...
}

Table Attachment
{
attachmentid int PK;
...
}
```

*Join Table:*

```
Ticket_Attachment_Join
{
tid  FK (ref to Ticket.ticketid)
aid PK FK(ref to Attachment.attachmentid)
}
```

**Mappings:**
*Ticket.hbm.xml:*

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Tickets" table="Ticket">
    ...
    <list name="attachmentsList" table="Ticket_Attachment_Join" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="ticketid"/>
           <list-index column="index_col"/>
            <many-to-many column="attachmentId" unique="true" class="Attachments" />
    </list>

...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to ask that in which table i should put  column **index_col** (`<list-index...>`column)? In Attachment table or in join table?? Is it neccessary to put index_col for lists in the table which represents lists(Here 'Attachment' table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be on `Ticket_Attachment_Join` as it is the table you are refering to in list mapping.

```
 <list name="attachmentsList" table="Ticket_Attachment_Join" 
                                      cascade="save-update">
```

And if you don't need any indexed collections you can map that `attachmentsList` using `<bag>` then you don't need that `<list-index column="index_col"/>` mapping at all.